# RSS feed that uses native Windows 10 notifications?

Tags: windows, rss

I've read of a bunch of RSS readers that give notification, even on this site but not one that uses the built in notification function on Windows 10. I want a lightweight program that just gives me a native notification instead of these ancient programs that make their own custom ones.

Comment: RSS is a web standard unlike Windows 10 notifications.

Comment: The above comment is not of much relevance there could be a desktop application that monitors Web Standard RSS feed and uses the Windows 10 Standard Notification to tell of an update to open the app...